# "Request failed with status code 403" error when downloading from Android SDK Manager

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk

I am facing the following error everywhere so in Android Studio when I download tools and SDK:

```
Packages to install: 
- Sources for Android 31 (sources;android-31)
- Android SDK Platform 31 (platforms;android-31)
Preparing "Install Sources for Android 31 (revision 1)".
Downloading http://dl.google.com/android/repository/sources-31_r01.zip
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Sources for Android 31: Request failed with status code 403.
"Install Sources for Android 31 (revision 1)" failed.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 31 (revision 1)".
Downloading http://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-31_r01.zip
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Platform 31: Request failed with status code 403.
"Install Android SDK Platform 31 (revision 1)" failed.
Failed packages:
- Sources for Android 31 (sources;android-31)
- Android SDK Platform 31 (platforms;android-31)
```